# Spring boot websockets with SockJS fallback - not working as is is supposed to

Tags: spring-websocket

I am trying to communicate using websockets just as in all the tutorials for spring boot and websockets (org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.18.RELEASE).

I did the tutorial with

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
}
```

Which only works with SockJS client (like in most of the tutorials on the web). When I am trying to connect using Websocket not SockJS I keep getting

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

It turned out that the real Websocket works only wthout the .withSockJS fallback

```
registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
```

That means the fallback is not really a fallback as it does not work with Websockets then. Is there a way to have both on the same endpoints or do I need to have simply multiple endpoints, one for sockJS and one for websockets?